# FullCalendar Scheduler timeline not working in rails view (rails 5.2)

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, fullcalendar-scheduler

This is my code in file home.html.erb. These are the assets I am using, when I run this as a simple HTML file, it shows fine, but when I pass it to Ruby on Rails html.erb file, only the timeline views are not showing the events.

**This is the example in pure HTML:**

[image: Pure HTML]

**This is the example in rails html.erb:**

[image: html.erb]

```
<%= stylesheet_link_tag('fullcalendar/packages/core/main.min.css') %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag('fullcalendar/packages/timeline/main.min.css') %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag('fullcalendar/packages/resource-timeline/main.min.css') %>
<%= stylesheet_link_tag('fullcalendar/packages/bootstrap/main.min.css') %>

<%= javascript_include_tag('fullcalendar/packages/core/main.min.js') %>
<%= javascript_include_tag('fullcalendar/packages/core/main.min.js') %>
<%= javascript_include_tag('fullcalendar/packages/interaction/main.min.js') %>
<%= javascript_include_tag('fullcalendar/packages/resource-timeline/main.min.js') %>
<%= javascript_include_tag('fullcalendar/packages/resource-common/main.min.js') %>
<%= javascript_include_tag('fullcalendar/packages/daygrid/main.min.js') %>
<%= javascript_include_tag('fullcalendar/packages/timegrid/main.min.js') %>
<%= javascript_include_tag('fullcalendar/packages/timeline/main.min.js') %>
<%= javascript_include_tag('fullcalendar/packages/resource-daygrid/main.min.js') %>
<%= javascript_include_tag('fullcalendar/packages/resource-timegrid/main.min.js') %>
<%= javascript_include_tag('fullcalendar/packages/bootstrap/main.min.js') %>

<script>
   document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
   var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
   var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, { 
      schedulerLicenseKey: 'XXX-XX-XXX-XXX-XXX',
   plugins: [ 'interaction', 'resourceTimeline', 'resourceDayGrid','resourceTimeGrid', 'bootstrap' ],  

  header: {
    left: 'today prev,next',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'resourceTimelineDay, resourceTimelineTenDay, resourceTimelineMonth, dayGridMonth '
  },
  aspectRatio: 1.5,
  defaultView: 'resourceTimelineDay',
  editable: true,
  selectable: true,

  resources: [
    { id: 'a', servicio: 'BR', title: 'GCV' },
    { id: 'b', servicio: 'BR', title: 'ABC' }

  ],
```

**events are referenced to resources**

```
  events: [
  {
      title: 'CINEPOLIS',
      start: '2019-03-21',
      resourceId: 'a',
      color: 'green'
    },
    {
      title: 'OPERADORA ZIBATA',
      start: '2019-03-21',
      end: '2019-03-10',
      resourceId: 'a'
    },
    {
      title: 'FLEX N GATE',
      start: '2019-03-21T16:00:00',
      end: '2019-03-23T16:00:00',
      resourceId: 'b'
    },
  ]
});

calendar.render();
});

</script>

</head>
```

The calendar looks fine, but doest show events when I see the options 'resourceTimelineDay, resourceTimelineTenDay, resourceTimelineMonth,....

Any hint you can help me.

Comment: Is the code identical in both files? Since at the end of the day it's just some HTML placed in a browser I can't see how what you named the file on the server would do to affect it. Unless some rails code runs server side which changed the output somehow. Have you looked in your browser's developer tools for anything odd e.g. console errors or CSS or JS files not loading correctly?

Comment: the html is called calendario.html and the rails is called calendario.html.erb, the difference is just the embedded ruby code, however, when I select the TimeGrid view, events shows correctly

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved. The problem was the license key.